# How to properly set up dockerized django app with SSL handling using self-signed certificate and mod_wsgi-express?

Tags: django, ssl, docker, mod-wsgi

I am using `grahamdumpleton/mod-wsgi-docker:python-3.4-onbuild` docker image and I run the django app inside with the command:

```
--allow-localhost --server-name 0.0.0.0 --startup-log --log-to-terminal --working-directory . \
--https-only --ssl-certificate-file /app/keys/server.crt --ssl-certificate-key-file \
/app/keys/server.key --https-port 8443 --application-type module datapie.wsgi`
```

I bind the port 8007 on my local machine to port 8443 of the container. I created self-signed certificate with FQDN set to `*`.

The problem is I get the `403` response when trying to access the server on `https://localhost:8007`. When trying to connect from inside the container everything works fine.

Any advice on how to set this up properly?

Comment: I somewhat doubt you can use ``0.0.0.0`` as the ``--server-name`` option. Using IP addresses like that in Apache when using named virtual hosts doesn't usually work. You should probably use a proper FQDN with it matching whatever hostname the service is exposed as. Using ``--allow-localhost`` may not be enough due to the fact it is inside of a Docker container and not strictly accessed via ``127.0.0.1``.

Comment: The service is resolved by ip as it only communicates with other services. I wanted to secure the connection between them using SSL. Isn't there a possibility to skip the hostname verification?

Comment: Is the client service in another linked container? If it is, can it use the service name that is usually stuck in the ``/etc/hosts`` file by Docker. Then use that same name for ``--server-name``.

Comment: No, it isn't. The client service is not dockerized. It connects to the host machine on exposed port.

Comment: Can the client at least for now manually set a ``Host`` header in the request, with a value of a fake host name the same as what you use for ``--server-name``. I'll have to think about a solution. I prefer to support the proper way of handling HTTPS and SSL certificates. Using IP address like this isn't the way it is generally done.

Comment: Yes, I could try this. Thanks.